# Refer to last dataframe in a for loop in R

Tags: r

I developed a code to read all csv files in a directory into R, create a dataframe for each csv file individually and title that dataframe an appropriate name. This has created 5 dataframes named D001, D002, D003, D004, D005. The last file, D005, ends with some text:

```
tail(D005)
                                              Lapse    Z
20208                                        813.570 -154
20209                                        813.610   26
20210                                        813.651   -4
20211                                        813.691  -58
20212                                        813.731 -202
20213 ; 813 stopping logging: shutdown: switched off
```

With the first column data classed "numeric" I receive the following error due to this row:

> Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
>     scan() expected 'a real', got ';813stoppinglogging:shutdown:switchedoff'

I have tried a number of commands using read.csv with the first column data classed "character" to overwrite this text,

```
including na.strings = "NA", fill = "", comment.char = "NA", encoding = "unknown"
```

and nothing has worked for me.

I can remove the row by `D005<-D005[-nrow(D005),]` but would prefer to do it by reference to the last dataframe created by my for loop rather than naming the dataframe, the reason being that when repeated in other file directories the last dataframe will not always be `D005`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try: `fill = T, quote = ""`

Comment: I think you have to comment out the last line in your original file.. otherwise how can R know what to read? Alternatively, try to set the col class to character, and process it in R by writing some code that removes the row if it contains text or something.

Comment: Suggestion: putting your dataframes in a list might save you a lot of trouble down the road. You can then access them through a variety of ways instead of relying on functions such as get, parse, eval, etc.

Comment: A.Val I tried your suggestions and they did not work for me

Comment: konvas, any idea how to remove the row if it contains the text in R?